# How to debug an unmanaged server extension in Neo4j3

Tags: java, neo4j

How can I debug the unmanaged server extensions in Neo4j 3.

I have quite a complicated plugin which I'm migrating from Neo4j 2 to Neo4j 3.

When I add the plugin to the plugin folder and start Neo4j after several seconds I see a message

> Starting Neo4j failed: org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-20bef39e@312b9bee==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,-1,false

I see more or less the same logs I see with an example extension that actually worked. You can see the logs here https://github.com/whatsthebeef/neo4j-test/blob/master/log2.txt

Are there any tricks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! \o/

So, let’s get to the bottom of this: Neo4j is just a **big** Java application.

Recipe:

1. Add `neo4j-harness` to your project.
2. Configure In-Process Neo4j server.
3. Add your extension there.
4. Start everything.

After this, you can debug your extension and Neo4j itself as standard Java application.

Links:

- [Testing extension with neo4j-harness](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#server-unmanaged-extensions-testing)
- [My blog post about testing unmanaged extensions](https://vrublevsky.me/neo4j/java/how-to-run-tests-against-neo4j-database-with-unmanaged-extension.html) (this one is for 2.2.5, but idea is still the same)
- [Sample project which uses neo4j-harness in tests](https://github.com/FylmTM/neo4j-unmanaged-extension-example/) (probably you are interested in [this](https://github.com/FylmTM/neo4j-unmanaged-extension-example/blob/master/src/test/java/io/graphgeeks/neo4j/extension/example/resource/util/Neo4jTestServer.java) class)

I will copy code sample from docs here, just to have all information in one place:

```
serverControls = TestServerBuilders.newInProcessBuilder()
            .withExtension(EXTENSION_MOUNT_POINT, ResourcesRootMarker.class)
            .newServer();
// EXTENSION_MOUNT_POINT - where to mount your extension, e.g. - "/myextension"
// ResourcesRootMarker.class - this class is located in the same package with JAX-RS resources
```

Comment: This was really useful and has helped me fix some potential future issues however I haven't actually advanced from where I was when I asked the question. My extension is setup correctly in the harness but when I deploy to the actual server I see the same error message and there are no other error messages on the  logs or deployment debug methods I can try.

Comment: So just to clarify it doesn't get to the point where I can see logs from my own extension because the deployment process fails.

Comment: @zode64 - try to enable "DEBUG" level logging for Neo4j and see if it can show something meaningful. Additionally - explore your extension "Maven dependency tree". Maybe some of your dependencies in extension now clashes with Neo4j dependencies. You can do it with maven itself, or with IntelliJ.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: I have logback configured in the extension to debug but it doesn't get to the point where it actually starts producing output as it seems to be before extension deployment is complete.

Answer (score 0):

FylmTM's answer got me moving.

The other thing worth noting is that for some reason (on my version at least) the neo4j.log file was at this location

> ~/Library/Application\ Support/Neo4j\ Community\ Edition/logs/neo4j.log

Where as the other logs are in the logs dir.